# Prepared Statement and bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement

I was using normal queries previously. But recently started to use prepared statements. I have this question in mind

**My Question**

Let's say I have a table called `files` with column names `id, name, privilege, acceptance`. I need to select only the value of `privilege`. When using `bind_result` part, do I need to give all column names inside? or just `privilege` will do? 
Means, do I need to give this way

```
$naming = $_POST['naming'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM files WHERE name = ?'; 
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $naming); 
    $stmt->execute();
```

`$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $privilege, $acceptance);` **OR**

`$stmt->bind_result($privilege);`

```
$stmt->fetch();
}
$db->close();
```

**Next question** is, how query will know that `$id` belongs to database `id` column, `$name` belongs to database `name` column, `$privilege` belongs to database `privilege` column and `$acceptance` belongs to database `acceptance` column, if we are using `$stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $privilege, $acceptance);`

**Last question** is, how should I get the value of these variables to use later in PHP? For the normal query, I can use something like `$row['id']`, `$row['name']`, `$row['privilege']`, `$row['acceptance']` etc after fetch results. But for prepared statements how to do that?

Comment: Why not __read a manual__ http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php?

Comment: If you only want the one column - only select it - don't do `SELECT *` for the sake of it.

Comment: @NigelRen So it means if I use *, then i need to give all column names in bind_result right?

Comment: In documentation is says 'Note that all columns must be bound after...'.  The problem I try to avoid is that if the table definition changes, this code will fail when using * even though you may not be interested in the new columns.